# Should I be worried after clicking on attachment in scam email?

Tags: iphone, mail.app, email, ios, malware

I received the email in the screenshot, which I'm fairly sure is a scam. I clicked on the attachment in the Mail app on my iPhone 6 (iOS 9.2). Note that I didn't unzip the attachment. Should I be concerned that clicking on the attachment will be harmful?

[image]

Comment: I don't think the iPhone can open zip files. If not, then you are safe.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the harm you feel you are exposed to? Loss of privacy? Concern that an email is marked as valid? Remote code execution? Change settings?

Answer (score 1):

You should be safe on your iPhone, normally these scam mails hope to be open on PCs where they can run scripts. your iPhone will not open the zip automatically, you would have to use a third party app.

You should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine - Apple are pretty solid at blocking anything nefarious from running that shouldn't be.

If you want to be extra careful I'd get onto a different device than your phone (a desktop/laptop computer) and change your email password from there - just in case something bad was left behind. There's some other tips over here in the FAQs section:
https://www.verified.org/articles/guides/how-to-verify-emails